# Expression trees - parameter not mapped from lambda function argument to Expression Parameter

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I am trying to wrap my head around Expression trees and I came to the below issue which I can not resolve. I am trying to generate a simple lambda function to check whether an integer value is even:

```
        public static Func<int, bool> Generate_IsEven_Func()
        {
            var numParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "numParam");
            var returnValue = Expression.Variable(typeof(bool), "returnValue");

            var consoleWL = typeof(Console).GetMethod(nameof(Console.WriteLine), new[] { typeof(int) });
            
            var body = Expression.Block(
                 // Scoping the variables
                 new[] { numParam, returnValue },

                 // Printing the current value for numParam
                 Expression.Call(
                     null,
                     consoleWL,
                     numParam
                     ),

                 // Assign the default value to return
                 Expression.Assign(returnValue, Expression.Constant(false, typeof(bool))),

                 // If the numParam is even the returnValue becomes true
                 Expression.IfThen(
                            Expression.Equal(
                                Expression.Modulo(
                                    numParam,
                                    Expression.Constant(2, typeof(int))
                                    ),
                                Expression.Constant(0, typeof(int))
                                ),
                            Expression.Assign(returnValue, Expression.Constant(true, typeof(bool)))
                        ),

                 // value to return
                 returnValue
                );

            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(body, numParam).Compile();
            return lambda;
        }
```

When I call the newly created lambda function it appears that the value I pass as an argument is not 'mapped' with the respective expression parameter - `numParam`. Within the block expression I make a call to the `Console.WriteLine` method to check the current value of `numParam` and it is 0 every time:

```
  var isEvenMethod = Generate_IsEven_Func();
  var cond = isEvenMethod(21);
  Console.WriteLine(cond);

  // Prints:
  // 0
  // True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not include `numParam` in the array of variables you're passing as the first parameter to `Expression.Block(...)` - right now you're essentially creating a new `numParam` variable within the block that is unrelated to the `numParam` parameter passed to the lambda. Since the variable is automatically initialized with the default value for `int` (0), that explains the output you're seeing.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot ! This scoping thing is still a bit unclear to me when it comes to Expression trees.